# django @cache_page decorator not setting a cache

Tags: python, django, caching, redis, django-redis

Here's my cache setting:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis.client.DefaultClient',
        }
    }
}
```

And a very basic `view` with `cache_page` decorator

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@cache_page(60*1)
def sawan_ko_jhari(request):
    data = request.data.get('name')
    return JsonResponse({"success": True, "data": data}, safe=False)
```

I've been checking cache keys for every request sent.. and I get empty array.

[image]

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: POST requests are not cached, only GET and HEAD requests are cached. Use GET instead?

Comment: @IainShelvington I see.. so to cache POST requests.. I have to explicitly set key-values for that?